# How can I set the level on a custom python logger?

Tags: python, logging

I have a custom python logger

```
# logger.py

import logging
#logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

c_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
c_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

c_format = logging.Formatter('%(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
c_handler.setFormatter(c_format)

logger.addHandler(c_handler)
```

I have set the level to DEBUG, but only WARNINGS (and above) are shown

```
from ..logger import logger
...
logger.debug('this is a debug log message')
logger.warning('too hot to handle')
...
```

> my_module.logger:too hot to handle

if I uncomment the line

```
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
```

then I get the DEBUG level, but two copies of the message

> my_module.logger - DEBUG - this is a debug log message

> DEBUG:my_module.logger:this is a debug log message

> my_module.logger - WARNING - too hot to handle

> WARNING:my_module.logger:too hot to handle

I am not importing *logging* at any other point in the package

How should I configure the logger?

Comment: According to [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.setLevel), a handler processes messages with the set level *and all higher levels*.

Comment: I have read that, so why does c_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG) not work?

Comment: `logging.basicConfig` adds a StreamHandler. From the documentation.

`logging.basicConfig` basic configuration for the logging system by creating a StreamHandler with a default Formatter and adding it to the root logger. The functions debug(), info(), warning(), error() and critical() will call basicConfig() automatically if no handlers are defined for the root logger.

Comment: I added a TLDR (solution) to my answer. Kindly check it out.

Comment: We posted solutions simultaneously :) Yours is the more erudite, mine includes what I consider to be the crux of the matter: logger.propagate = False

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR Use `logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)`

---

According to [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.setLevel), a handler processes messages with a level equal to or higher than the handler is set to (via `.setLevel()`).

But also note, emphasis mine:

> When a logger is created, the level is set to `NOTSET` (which causes all messages to be processed when the logger is the root logger, **or delegation to the parent when the logger is a non-root logger**). Note that the root logger is created with level `WARNING`.

So without `logging.basicConfig`, there's no "root logger" at program startup, and your first `getLogger()` creates a stub root logger with default level WARNING, and your logger with level NOTSET (which fallbacks to that of the root logger). As a result your `logger.debug` message is thrown away before it gets handled.

With `logging.basicConfig`, you explicitly create a root logger with the given level *and [**a StreamHandler** with default Formatter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.basicConfig)*. Your new `getLogger()` is attached to the root logger and any log record is [propagated](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.propagate) to the root logger - thus printing twice with a different formatter (the default one indeed).

The stub root logger created by the first call to `getLogger()` has no handler attached so any propagated record is not printed out.

If you want to have full control over your logging facility, it's better to give your logger an explicit level than relying on `basicConfig`, which creates a root logger that you may not want:

```
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

Comment: Your answer is wrong in some details. The root logger always exists once you've done `import logging` anywhere; `basicConfig()` optionally sets its level and adds a handler to it, either a `StreamHandler` or a `FileHandler` depending on the arguments passed to `basicConfig()`. To have multiple handlers, the right thing to have done would have been to call `basicConfig()` with the handlers argument with a `StreamHandler` and a `FileHandler` configured appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

Having read the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.setLevel) again I realise that *propagate* is the attribute that I need to use to turn off the ancestor *logging* output. So my logger becomes

```
# logger.py

import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
logger.propagate = False

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

c_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
c_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

c_format = logging.Formatter('%(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
c_handler.setFormatter(c_format)

logger.addHandler(c_handler)
```

And I get just one log message and the debug level is used

Comment: You've got a bug there - your `logger.propagate = False` code happens before you instantiate `logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)`